# MongoDB - update embedded document AND the document itself

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to update both the document and the embedded array element from this document in one query?

E.g.

```
Team:
{
   MembersCount: 1,
   Members: [
      {
         Id: 1,
         Role: 1
       }]
 }
```

Sample query would have to `increment MemberCount`, `push an element to Members array` and `change the first member's role`.

My research indicates that you can update the document or update array's element, but not both, since the query has to point either on the document or to the specific element, but perhaps I'm missing something.

EDIT:
Now I know that it's impossible to add an element to Scores array and modify other element in the same array (the index of this element would change - that is my explanation).

Comment: From my personal experience, I can say We can't update array & its object property at the same time. So we have to use two query for the above result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, that you can't add to an array while updating an element of it at the same time. In MongoDB v3.2, you should see an error message:

```
Cannot update 'Members.0.Role' and 'Members' at the same time
```

An alternative approach is to utilise [cursor.forEach()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/). 
For example:

```
/* Find a document using _id */
db.collection.find({
                     "_id":ObjectId("578cda18006d485d118c3b79")
                  })
                  .forEach(function(doc){
                                 /* Increment MemberCount */
                                 doc['MemberCount']+=1; 
                                 /* Push an element to Members array */
                                 doc["Members"].push({"Id":2, "Role":9});
                                 /* Change the first member's role */
                                 doc["Members"][0]["Role"] = 3;
                                 /* Save*/
                                 db.collection.save(doc)
                                })
```

Although you need to re-consider whether this is the most suitable [data model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) for your application use case.